# Facebook open graph - Meta Tags In Body

Tags: facebook

i am solwing problem with facebook open graph. This is site where is the problem http://www.freshmagazine.eu/. If you see source code, facebook meta og data are in head but facebook debugger always returns error https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/  - Meta Tags In Body. Could somebody help me pleas?
(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: In addition to what luschn said: You need to use absolute URLs for values such as `og:image`. Currently you have set a relative URL for that property, and that won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML shows several errors, you need to fix those: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.freshmagazine.eu%2F

After that, refresh the OG data in the debugger.